# Why does Pandas incorrectly evaluate the week count of the last day of the year?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime

```
import pandas as pd    

t1 = pd.Timestamp('2018-01-01')
print(t1.week)

t364 = pd.Timestamp('2018-12-30')
print(t364.week)

t365 = pd.Timestamp('2018-12-31')
print(t365.week)
```

Output:

```
1
52
1
```

If you relying on week number as input it seriously screws your count ifs, max ifs etc.

Comment: Might this have something to with that `364/7 = 52` and `365/7 = 52.1428571429`?

Comment: It doesn't. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date in particular 'Weeks start with Monday. Each week's year is the Gregorian year in which the Thursday falls',  So t365 falls into the first week of 2019

Comment: That is it. Although quite illogical.

Comment: It's either this system or having incomplete weeks (starting not on Mondays and not having 7 days)

Comment: "do" with capture group "e" with optional "s"… Argh, damn brain…

Answer (score 1):

As per @zeeMonkeez's comment, `pandas` uses [ISO week date conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date).

A workaround is to convert to `datetime`, extract days from start of year, then divide by 7:

```
import pandas as pd
from math import ceil

def weeker(x):
    return ceil(x.to_pydatetime().timetuple().tm_yday / 7)

t1 = pd.Timestamp('2018-01-01')
print(t1.week, weeker(t1))  # 1 1

t364 = pd.Timestamp('2018-12-30')
print(t364.week, weeker(t364))  # 52 52

t365 = pd.Timestamp('2018-12-31')
print(t365.week, weeker(t365))  # 1 53
```